# How to change slider color according to percentage

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code below to create a range slider:

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #e9eefc;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #313a46;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="mb-3 slidecontainer">
        <input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is to fill range with color, starting with blue for low percentage and ending with green for high percentage, with gradient, something like this:

20%:
[image: 20%]

100%:
[image: 100%]

Any ideias ? thanks

Comment: What is the event that represents 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an animation that's paused and manually set the animation-delay property.

The animation is 100s. Set the animation-delay to the current value. Add `style="animation-delay: -50s"` to your input. This would be the default value -50 for 50%, -20 for 20%, etc.

Then add `oninput="this.style.animationDelay = -this.value + 's'"` to the input. So as the slider moves, it changes the animationDelay to the percentage.

Then in CSS, on `.slider`, change `background` to `currentColor` and add `animation: color-range 100s linear forwards paused;`.
Finally, add to css:

```
@keyframes color-range {
    0% { color: steelblue }
    100% { color: green }
}
```

```js
let setColor = (el) => {
    el.style.animationDelay = `-${el.value}s`;
  el.style.background = `linear-gradient(90deg, currentColor ${el.value}%, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) ${el.value}%)`;
};
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  outline: none;
  animation: color-range 100s linear forwards paused;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, currentColor 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 50%);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes color-range {
  0% { color: steelblue }
  100% { color: green }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="mb-3 slidecontainer">
        <input class="slider"
          type="range"
          min="0"
          max="100"
          step="5"
          style="animation-delay: -50s"
          oninput="setColor(this)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you !! It's almost this.. Do you know how can I fill the color just on the left side of the range button ? like the image I sent

Comment: @HoofHarted Didn't know you could 'pause' on a keyframe, great css solution.

Comment: @NewProgrammer, that's going to involve a little more work. You will have to create elements behind the slider that changes color and make the color of the actual slider transparent. Then the width will have to change so it always ends behind the slider.

Comment: Oh wait, I got it. I made changes above. Added a little JS function. Changed the `oninput` event. And changed the `background` property on `.slider`

Comment: Yeess ! It's exacly this.. thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this with some JavaScript, because it is too dynamic for just CSS/HTML on their own. You want to change the color whenever the value changes, so you can add a handler to the `change` event of the slider and then set the background color with the element's `style.background` property. For example:

```js
function setSliderBackground(target) {     
  // Add your background logic here:
  if (target.value > 50) {
    target.style.background = "red";
  } else {
    target.style.background = "green";
  }
}

// Bind the event handler to all of the sliders with the slider class:
for (let slider of document.querySelectorAll(".slider")) {
  slider.addEventListener("change", event => setSliderBackground(event.target));
  // Set the background once on initial load so it is correct before the user interacts:
  setSliderBackground(slider);
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #e9eefc;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #313a46;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="mb-3 slidecontainer">
        <input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, yes, it's similar to what you did, but it would be better using a gradient from blue to green, do you know how can I do it ?